# Prevent deletes in a versioned FC at the application level

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, delete

In [Prevent deletes in a versioned FC at the database level](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371588) (a related question), we determined that it's **not** possible to prevent deletes from a versioned FC via functionality in the database.

As an alternative, is it possible to prevent features from being deleted from a versioned FC—via logic in the **application** (ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1)?

Comment: No.  Nothing can prevent a determined user with SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE access from deleting a feature.

Comment: @Vince I like the ESRI universe, but it *is* kind of like the wild west. Anything goes! No data integrity required!

Comment: Hey, you granted them that access. All you need to do is rewrite ArcMap from scratch in ArcObjects, or write a custom web app that doesn't offer a delete option.

Comment: @Vince Right, but I didn't grant them DELETE access willingly. I was forced to because the data is versioned.